# Adding Calibration Data For Noise Model

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise

I am building a custom noise model using Qiskit's NoiseModel class. I want to incorporate full range of calibration data, say for 7 qubit machine. I am not sure how to incorporate calibration features like ['id', 'sx', 'rz', 'rx', 'x', 'reset'] errors besides readout lengths, frequency and anharmonicity into the custom noise model using the inbuilt functions in NoiseModel class. I am not sure under which category will the gate lengths and errors to add since there are:

1. Quantum errors
2. Readout errors
   that can be incorporated into NoiseModel class.
   This link https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/3_building_noise_models.html does not mention how to incorporate frequency and anharmonicity in the NoiseModel object. Since I am new to the world of quantum computing, I do not understand how to use these errors below with regards to calibration data: 1. phase amplitude damping error 2. amplitude damping error 3. phase damping error 4. LocalNoisePass 5. RelaxationNoisePass

My calibration data dictionary for 1 qubit is in the form

{'Anharmonicity-Q0': -0.3415,
'Frequency-Q0': 5157553795.720,
'Readout_Length-Q0': 6.7555e-07,
'T1-Q0': 206.1588,
'T2-Q0': 104.1353,
'sx0': 0.00015504,
'sx0_time': 35.5556}

Thanks

Comment: take a look at these tutorials https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/tree/master/tutorials/simulators

Comment: Thanks, the link is useful. However, it does not mention how to incorporate frequency and anharmonicity in the NoiseModel object. Since I am new to the world of quantum computing, I do not understand how to use these errors below with regards to calibration data: 
1. phase amplitude damping error
2. amplitude damping error
3. phase damping error
4. LocalNoisePass
5. RelaxationNoisePass

Comment: for incorporate frequency and anharmonicity you need qiskit-pulse.
https://cahyati2d.medium.com/qubit-spectroscopy-my-lab-d9ac79c82ce1 might help a little.

Comment: Thanks @poig for the link. Could you tell me if any of the calibration data mentioned above falls into category of these errors provided in the NoiseModel class:
1. amplitude damping error 
2. phase damping error 
3. LocalNoisePass 
4. RelaxationNoisePass

Comment: Those NoiseModel class you mention for 1,2,3 are tools for making the specific type of error, nothing doing with calibration data. you can see more about it, with docs, notebook, or source code, to understand the math or logic behind it.

Comment: for the RelaxationNoisePass, you can use to make a gate that does the noise, that can append into the circuit. as what docs says:  
Add duration dependent thermal relaxation noise after instructions.

Comment: By what you said earlier, if I want to build a custom noise model which incorporates X, SX, ID, RZ:
 1. I do it this way for 1 qubit, X = x_error,
X_error = [pauli_error([('X', bit_flip_error), ('I', 1-bit_flip_error)]), 
NoiseModel.add_quantum_error(X_error, "x", [0]),

2. ID = id0,
ID_error = depolarizing_error(id_error, 1), 
NoiseModel.add_quantum_error(ID_error, "id", [0]), 

 I repeat the same for SX, RZ the way I did for ID?

Comment: from my understanding, it should be in that way, if didn't miss understand your calibration data mean.

Comment: Thank you @poig